# Disable logging in hapijs

Tags: node.js, logging, hapi.js

I want to disable all logs from `server.log` while testing in order to keep my console clean.

I read in the [docs](http://hapijs.com/api) that I have to set `debug: false` in the server options. I use [Glue](https://github.com/hapijs/glue) for server initialization, so I added the following snippet to my manifest:

```
{
  "server": {
    "debug": false
  }
}
```

It didn't help, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [good](https://github.com/hapijs/good) plugin one can set the events he wants to log.

It's also possible to remove good to mute the logs.